# fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Tags: github-actions, cicd, lighthouse-ci

I'm trying to integrate Lighthouse CI into my CI/CD to generate reports on my applications performance. I'm using GitHub Actions, and other jobs like building the app and generating a SonarCloud scan are working.

However Lighthouse CI is not working. The error is: Error: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled

Code:

```
# This workflow will do a clean installation of node dependencies, cache/restore them, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

env:
  REGISTRY: ghcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ github.repository }}

jobs:
  sonarcloud:
    name: SonarCloud
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Shallow clones should be disabled for a better relevancy of analysis
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  # Needed to get PR information, if any
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}

  lighthouse:
    name: Lighthouse CI
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.LHCI_GITHUB_APP_TOKEN }}
          submodules: recursive
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
      - name: Run the Lighthouse CI
        run: |
          npm install -g @lhci/cli@0.6.x
          lhci autorun

  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [ 16.x ]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm ci
      - run: npm run build --if-present
      - run: npm test

      - name: Log in to the Container registry
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
          tags: |
            type=ref,event=branch
            type=sha

      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Screenshot of GitHub Actions:

[image: Github Actions]

Answer (score 0):

hi，i find a issue for the problem。

https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/664

“For a simple checkout indeed no PAT is required.”

so you can try remove token

```yaml
 lighthouse:
    name: Lighthouse CI
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          # token: ${{ secrets.LHCI_GITHUB_APP_TOKEN }}  // remove 
          submodules: recursive
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
      - name: Run the Lighthouse CI
        run: |
          npm install -g @lhci/cli@0.6.x
          lhci autorun
```